# How to watch for count of new lines in tail

Tags: tail, watch, command-line-interface

I want to do something like this:

```
watch tail -f | wc -l
#=> 43
#=> 56
#=> 61
#=> 44
#=> ...
```

It counts new lines of tail each second

/ Linux, CentOs

To be more clear. I have got something like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/my_process/*.log | grep error
```

I am reading some error messages. And now I want to count them. How many ~ errors I have got in a second. So one line in a log is one error in a proccess.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to watch appended lines, it is enough to use `tail -f /path/to/file` alone. If you want to watch file lines, you can use `watch wc -l /path/to/file`.

Comment: @Khaled, I need to watch how many new lines were appended

Comment: I use tail with regex for a number of files, and I want to see  how many lines are appended to all of this files through a time

Comment: Hmpfh.  `tail -f /var/log/my_process/*.log |grep error > /tmp/error.lines & ; watch wc /tmp/error.lines` ?  Then do math.

Comment: @cjc it works, thanks! :) you should at it as ab answer

Comment: Hmm, OK, though I feel there's probably a better way that I'm not seeing right now.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've recently discovered pv, and it's really cool, you could do something like

`tail -f logfile | pv -i2 -ltr > /dev/null`

- -i2 = count every 2 seconds
- -l  = count lines
- -t  = print time
- -r  = show rate

Comment: pv is a command that is not installed by default. Try doing `sudo apt install pv` before if it fails for you

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty method.  You basically want to break the `tail` and the `watch wc` into separate parts, and do something like:

```
tail -f /var/log/my_process/*.log |grep error > /tmp/error.lines &
watch wc /tmp/error.lines
```

at which point, you can do math to get an errors/sec number.  But, if you're just doing this for an one-off examination of your error rate, quick-and-dirty might be good enough.

Answer (score 3):

In case pv  is not available  it can be  done  with  perl:

Every one second:

```
tail -f  recycleBack*out  | perl -e 'while (<>) {$l++;if (time > $e) {$e=time;$i++;print "$i=> $l\n";$l=0}}'
```

Every 10 seconds

```
tail -f  recycleBack*out  | perl -e 'while (<>) {$l++;if (time > $e+10) {$e=time;$i++;print "$i=> $l\n";$l=0}}'
```

Sample output:

```
1=> 1
2=> 1523
3=> 1339
4=> 1508
5=> 1785
6=> 1587
7=> 1770
8=> 1432
9=> 1339
10=> 1555
11=> 1663
12=> 1693
13=> 1647
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/my_process/*.log | perl -pe '$_ = "$. $_"'
```

It prints the line number in front of each line.

Comment: 1) That's not what the OP is looking for and 2) `nl` will do this, not requiring the call out to perl.